# Control del error de acceso a las propiedades, leer json con javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy leyendo una variable json y extrayendo información del la misma.

los campos de las propiedades los tengo en un array. Todo va bien hasta que el campo que busco no existe

la aplicación da un error de tipo:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado todas las opciones que he encontrado en la red para controlar el error:

```
    1.var tipo = typeof PropModelo[HayarIndice(Nodos[j])].properties[nombreNivel][value]);
    if (tipo ==="undefined")  //error cuando carga la variable "tipo".
    2.if(PropModelo[HayarIndice(Nodos[j])].properties[nombreNivel][value] === void 0)//error cuando se mencionan las propiedades.
```

En resumen he probado todas las soluciones que se me han presentado por la red
y me sigue dando error siempre que se menciona:

> `PropModelo[HayarIndice(Nodos[j])].properties[nombreNivel][value]`

¿Cómo puedo controlar el error? necesito que las variables que no tengan éste campo no rompan la ejecución del programa.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías aportarnos un [MCVE](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? La respuesta es sencilla, necesitas averiguar si existe `PropModelo[HayarIndice(Nodos[j])]` antes de obtener `.properties`, pero podría reproducir tu problema y ver que es la solución correcta si das más código.

Comment: A falta de mcve he creado un ejemplo en el que creo una matriz de referencia desde la que obtener los datos, detectando cuáles de ellos no existen o no están definidos.

Comment: Hola @Clara-Arias-Del-Rey, ¿podrías confirmar si se solucionó tu problema con la explicación que te hice? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error te está diciendo que necesitas comprobar si existe `PropModelo[HayarIndice(Nodos[j])]` antes de obtener `.properties` ya que si el anterior es `undefined` éste no tiene la propiedad `properties`.

Prueba:

```
var tipo = typeof PropModelo[HayarIndice(Nodos[j])];
if (tipo === "undefined") ...
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo más complejo en el que se prueban todas las posibilidades:

```js
var PropModelo = [
  {
    properties:[
      ['hola']
    ]
  },
  {
    sinproperties:[[]]
  },
];
console.log(PropModelo);

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  if (typeof PropModelo[i] === 'undefined') {
    console.log("El índice PropModelo[" + i + "] no existe");
    continue;
  }
  if (typeof PropModelo[i].properties !== 'object') {
    console.log("PropModelo[" + i + "].properties no está definido");
    continue;
  }
  for (var a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
    if (typeof PropModelo[i].properties[a] === "undefined") {
      console.log("PropModelo[" + i + "].properties[" + a + "] no existe");
      continue;
    }
    for (var b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
      if (typeof PropModelo[i].properties[a][b] === "undefined") {
        console.log("PropModelo[" + i + "].properties[" + a + "][" + b + "] no existe");
      } else {
        console.log("Valor de PropModelo[" + i + "].properties[" + a + "][" + b + "]: " + PropModelo[i].properties[a][b]);
      }
    }
  }
}
/* Ahora en modo Chuck Norris, fíjate en el "undefined" de uno del (0,0,1) */
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  for (var a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
    for (var b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
      try {
        console.log("Valor de PropModelo[" + i + "].properties[" + a + "][" + b + "]: " + PropModelo[i].properties[a][b]);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("PropModelo[" + i + "].properties[" + a + "][" + b + "] no existe");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edito: Agrego bloque `try/catch` para mostrar el funcionamiento que tendría bajo él (notar el valor `undefined` obtenido al acceder a un índice no existente de una matriz existente.

Comment: Gracias! @OscarGarcia me has dado unas cuantas pistas pistas,  me funciona comprobando todos los niveles de la jerarquía.   

        var minodo = typeof PropModelo[HayarIndice(Nodos[j])];
        var niveles= typeof PropModelo[HayarIndice(Nodos[j])].properties;
 var campos = typeof PropModelo[HayarIndice(Nodos[j])].properties[nombreNivel];
     if ((minodo =="undefined")||(niveles=="undefined")||(campos=="undefined")) {....

Comment: Perdona, la única forma de poner código es a través de la edición de tu pregunta. Si lo intentas aquí no podrás hacerlo, saldrá como texto y se cortará al llegar al límite.

Comment: @ClaraAriasDelRey no puedes pegar código como comentario, se rompe el diseño, se corta y no se entiende. Respecto a tu pregunta, ¿se considera solucionada o tienes más dudas? Si es así, por favor, vota las respuestas que te hayan sido de utilidad y/o marca la que haya solucionado tu problema como tal. Y si tienes más dudas edita tu pregunta y deja un comentario para hacernos saber que lo has hecho para que revisemos tus cambios. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Casi lo tienes. Yo creo que comprobando directamente si es `undefined` te vale (pero sin las comillas) `if (array[propiedad]==undefined).....`

Comment: También lo he probado, y me sigue dando el error.Gracias

Comment: `typeof` es una construcción del lenguaje que devuelve una cadena de caracteres: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof si lo comparas con `undefined` buscará una variable con ese nombre (no existirá) y realizará la comparación con ella.

Comment: He editado la respuesta. Había copiado parte del código sin mirarlo bien. A lo que me refería es que puedes intentar recuperar directamente el valor del array y verificar si existe mirando si es undefined.

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que te comento: https://jsfiddle.net/fforcen/vu9kp0q6/

Verás que cuando lo ejecutas, por consola muestra `true` porque no existe.

Comment: Cierto, pero no funciona para una matriz de dos dimensiones. En cuanto la primera dimensión no está definida da error al intentar acceder a la segunda: https://jsfiddle.net/rq6okes0/

Comment: Disculpas, no había usado antes jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ekue6tj/

Comment: Claro, tendrías que comparar los datos por separa. Al fin y al cabo en JS puedes tratar los objetos como mapas de propiedades. Por eso tendrías que (siguiendo tu ejemplo de fiddle) evaluar la primera propiedad y, si existe, evaluar la segunda. Aquí te lo dejo: https://jsfiddle.net/fforcen/7ekue6tj/1/